# bash builtin read -p does not understand $@

Tags: bash, built-in

```
~$> function f { local opt; read -p "choose from args [ $@ ]:" opt; }
~$> f a b
-bash: read: `b ]:': not a valid identifier
```

The workaround I employed was

```
echo -ne "choose from args [ $@ ]:"; read opt;
           OR
local args="$@"
read -p "choose from args [ ${args} ]:" opt;
```

But can someone explain why it does not work with `read -p` .

Note: `read -p "choose from args [ $1 ]:"` seems to work just fine.
Using Platform Cygwin and debian 9. bash version 4.4.12 and 5.0.3.

Answer (score 4):

When there are multiple arguments `$@` expands to multiple words. It's as if you'd written:

```
read -p "choose from args[ a" "b ]:" opt
```

It sees `"b ]:"` as a separate argument not belonging to `-p`, interprets it as a variable name, and then declares that `b ]:` is not a valid identifier.

Use `$*` to ensure the arguments are always expanded as a single string.

```
read -p "choose from args [ $* ]:" opt
```